# Monotonicity described by barrier function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that for all $c\in [a,b]$, there is a continuous function $f_c : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ so that 
>   $$\begin{cases} f_c(c) = f(c), \\ f_c(x) \ge f(x) &\text{for all } x\in [a,b], \\ f'_c(c) \ge 0.\end{cases}$$
>   show that $f$ is then non-decreasing. That is $f(y)\ge f(x)$ if $y\ge x$.

If the last condition is changed to $>0$, then it is easy to check that using the continuity of $f$ and some open/close argument. However when one only have $\ge 0$, that $f_c$ might not be nondecreasing locally at $c$.

Any ideas/thoughts/hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose by contradiction that $f$ is not non-decreasing, so there exist two points $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $x<y$ and $f(x)>f(y)$. Now take
$$c=\sup \{ z \in (x,y) : f(z)> f(y) \}$$
Clearly $f(c)=f(y)$. Now, we have that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $z\in (c,c-\epsilon)$ such that $f(z)>f(c).$ Recalling that $f_c'(c)\ge0 $, by definition of derivative, we can choose an $\epsilon_1>0$ so that $f_c(c-h)\le f_c(c)$ for every $h\le \epsilon_1$. We know from before that there exists $z \in (c,c-\epsilon_1)$ such that $f(z)>f(c)$. Hence,
$$f(z)>f(c)=f_c(c)\ge f_c(z)$$
 a contradiction.

Comment: Actually I do not assume that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: You are right, but this just makes the proof a bit longer, i'll fix it now.

Comment: @JohnMa it should be correct now.

Comment: Actually $f_c(c) \ge 0$ alone does not imply that $f_c(c) \ge f_c(c-h)$ for all $h$ small. $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ at $x=0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: You're again right, I'm missing a step to complete the proof.